# Android Execute based on timer only once?

Tags: android, timer

I can run codes after every x seconds, but is there a way to only run a code once after x sec? Ex: I want to refresh a listview once after 1 second when a user click on a button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the delayed operation is a UI Event, use a `Handler`

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { 
              //my events
         } 
    }, 2000); //time in millis
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually recommend

> Timer

class in time related stuffs. but in this case i wont recommend you to use Timer as you need to execute the operation only one.
Why not simply use a

> **Thread**

and `sleep` it for 1000 millis. There you go. your 1 sec timer. :)